# How can I get Ubuntu 16.04 Driver Manager Tools?

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, 16.04, ubuntu-drivers

I want to get a tool to manage the drivers. How Can I get the tools? 
I know the tools like *Mini Driver Manager*, *Device Driver Manager*. 
But they do not support for Ubuntu16.04.